# What would be the formula for $\int uv$ in higher dimesions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $u,v: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ differntiable function. Then formally, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) v(x) dx= \left[u(x) \int v(x) dx\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( u'(x) \int v(x) dx \right )dx. $$

[Please correct me if the above formula is wrong or I  am missing some thing to make it rigorous]

Now suppose that $u, v: \mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb C$ ($n>1$) be functions.

> **My Question is**: What should be the right analogue of the above formula? What are the conditions on $u$ and $v$ we should impose? And what would be a formula (keeping the above formula in mind) for $\int_{\mathbb R^n} u(x) v(x) dx$?